# ELMAH MS SQL logs viewer

Tags: sql-server, elmah, viewer

We are using Elmah with MS SQL Server to log exceptions. The problem is that I do not find easy way how to navigate exceptions logged in database. Is there any Elmah SQL Server logs viewer or I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELMAH logs are designed to be viewed using the ELMAH handler aka elmah.axd (assuming you have it configured correctly).

You are supposed to go onto the site and go to the handler to see the errors.

For example:

```
http://example.com/elmah.axd
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the `httpHandler` used to view exceptions to your `web.config` file? Have a look at the example web.config here: http://code.google.com/p/elmah/downloads/detail?name=ELMAH-1.2-sample-web.config

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not specifically using MS-SQL as your question states and although it's a paid service, you could use [Elmah.io](https://elmah.io/) - a cloud based log viewer with a ton of neat features. Plus there's a free 30 day trial for you to test it out.

You can install a nuget package, which takes care of the integration into your apps for you [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/elmah.io/).

(Disclaimer: I am in no way affiliated with elmah.io).